# Node Router Admin or User Upate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to update the user if they are logged in or if they are admin.

this is my code

```
router.put("/:id", verifyTokenAndAuthorization / verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password) {
        req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, "process.env.PASS_SEC").toString()
    }

    try {
        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            $set: req.body,
        }, { new: true });
        res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
}
);
```

i dont know if its right way to write like this

```
verifyTokenAndAuthorization / verifyTokenAndAdmin
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What are `verifyTokenAndAuthorization / verifyTokenAndAdmin`?

Comment: Shouldn't an admin be logged in as well? :)

Comment: Oh yea... I feel stupid now lol.

Comment: verifyTokenAndAuthorization is to verify the jwt token of logged in user and veriFyTokenAndAdmin is to verify the token of the Admin

Comment: simple throw an exception in those methods verifyTokenAndAuthorization  and veriFyTokenAndAdmin if conditions do not match.